# I am moving a button within a frame ,after which it stops working . any suggestion?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am moving a frame, within which i have `UIButton`. The `UIButton` controls the movement of frame, after the completion of animation. The button stops working.

Why this occur in my case?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Does your button goes out of the viewcontroller's view frame ?

Comment: i think your button goes under  the any view thats why ur button `userInteraction` not respond . please put some code and check first this situation . Thanks